# Stop foobar2000 from grouping together MP3 and FLAC files on the album list

Tags: foobar2000, music-management

I have lots of albums in two formats, MP3 and FLAC. On the album list I need foobar to stop collating tracks together if they're different formats.

For example on the album list if foobar detected that there was an album which was in both FLAC and MP3 it would show two albums on the list instead of grouping it together as one.

Is this possible? Am I making sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could simply add `%codec%` to your view pattern.

For example:
In **Preferences: Media Library** > **Album List**, create a new view called "by artist/codec" and use the following pattern:

```
%<artist>%|%album%|%codec%|[[%discnumber%.]%tracknumber%. ][%track artist% - ]%title%
```

(The pipe <kbd>|</kbd> characters make it a separate level in the tree hierarchy.)

Answer (score 3):

> File > Preferences > Media Library > Restrict to: > "*.FLAC" (copy/paste without the ")

or

> File > Preferences > Media Library > Exclude: > "*.CUE; *.MP3; *.M3U" (copy/paste without the ")

Answer (score 1):

Right click the headers at the top of the playlist view, go to `Columns` > `File extension`, and then click the new field to sort by it. It will keep the sort settings you currently have, but also group them by file extension.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about the **Album List**, not the **Playlist View**.

Comment: Oh, that's my bad, read it too fast. Will delete in a few mins.

Comment: That's okay, I posted something about the Playlist View too, initially. :-)

Comment: Won't bother then :P